# ubuntu 16.04.01 startup application freeze the 'shell script' execution until login

Tags: bash, gnome, scripts, autostart

i have shell script added in the 'start application' launcher of ubuntu 16.04.01 and it had launched the terminal,but it had freeze the execution until i login and is there any modification change required to start the shell script & running fully without login
The GNOME VERSION IS: GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2??   I would check that's what you're running, as an updated *xenial* system should report itself as 16.04.7 if updates are fully applied. (have you really not applied any updates since 2017-August?? https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/08/05/ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-released/  and that date applies to ISO release, installed systems upgrade to it before the ISO's release date)   I would suggest updating your system, applying fixes & test again.  GNOME is also EOL on 16.04/xenial

Comment: Linux det-linux01 4.15.0-133-generic #137~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 02:55:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: that is kernel detail, not your release details.   As for GNOME - refer https://ubuntugnome.org/ "*Although Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.5 is supported until April 2019, we strongly encourage you to install the regular Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release which features a minimally customized GNOME desktop.*"  The 4.15 though implies you have updated, as 16.04.2 would be using 4.4 (GA) or 4.8 (HWE) kernels

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>3</platform>
 <minor>18</minor>
 <micro>2</micro>
 <distributor>Ubuntu</distributor>

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Comment: i would really appreciate if someone help on this issue and i got struck in between thanks

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.